# Why does YouTube have a large amount of empty space underneath and to the right of the video?

Tags: youtube, brave

Since today, my YouTube videos are formatted weirdly. On the right, you can see where my recommended videos are, and clearly the big gray gap in between is not normal. Especially with videos in portrait mode, it's even worse. There's like twice the video height of gray space below it before the comments show up. Does anyone know why this is?

Together with this, ads started showing up on my YouTube again. I am using Brave Browser, which has a built-in ad-blocker so I shouldn't see ads normally. I think the issues are likely related, but I have no idea what it is or how to fix it.

[image: video with empty space underneath above the title and to the right, with recommended videos on the far right]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select cinema mode in youtube.

This can be achieved using the small oblong icon at the bottom right of the video (hover over it to see the option):

[image]

or by pressing <kbd>t</kbd> (the keyboard shortcut for cinema mode)